# Scaling down image to a fixed dimension of 135x135

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have to scale down image of any dimension to a fixed dimension of 135x135, most imp thing I have to maintain good quality of scaled down image. I'm not much familiar with Image Processing algos. Can you guys suggest me any algorithm.

Comment: Do you work in a given environment? Like C# or Java? Or do you want to use a command line tool? Or do you want to write the actual algorithm yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the input image is square, say 1000x1000, you will first have to **crop** it to a square aspect ratio (1:1) then **scale** it down to 135x135 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly answer if you want to crop the image or deforming the image to fit in the box

Apply a 2d Sinc filter with the right size for the current scale factor.
Scan the new image and pick up pixels from the old one by just dividing.